# Hiding elements of an external site

Tags: javascript, css, html

Let us consider a link 
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cricket+images&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibhsXsqdPUAhVKP48KHcsCA8EQ_AUIBigB&biw=1600&bih=770

when we click on this link it directs to the google images with all elements

Now I want only images to be displayed and all other elements should be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Google has option to remove branding.
This link can help you 
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4542163?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

@Arun Varma you can do something like this

CSS

```
*{
visibility:hidden;}

* > img
{
visibility:visible !important;
}
```

only images will be visible.. hiding all other elements..

hope this helps..